# How to do FFMPEG live transcoding to HTML5 video from file(.MP4, .MKV) in PHP?

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm using windows, tried to follow this tutorial and downloaded the code: blog  page is http://sixserv.org/2010/11/30/live-transcoding-for-video-and-audio-streaming/ and the github https://github.com/4poc/php-live-transcode. It doesn't work, I'm getting some errors in mplayer saying "MPlayer has not identified the file you provided".

I just need a simple working live media transcoder that can work on most browsers even in mobile devices (HTML5) using FFMPEG in PHP. I've been searching this the entire time, I found nothing.